# Parsing tnsnames.ora using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, oracle, tnsnames

I am attempting to pull some information from my tnsnames file using regex.  I started with the following pattern:

`MYSCHEMA *? = *?[\W\w\S\s]*\(HOST *?= *?(?<host>\w+\s?)\)\s?\(PORT *?= *?(?<port>\d+)\s?\)[\W\w\S\s]*\(SERVICE_NAME *?= *?(?<servicename>\w+)\s?\)`

which worked fine when MYSCHEMA was the only schema in the file, but when there are other schemas listed after MYSCHEMA it matches all the way to the last schema.

I have since created a new pattern:

`MYSCHEMA *=\s*\(DESCRIPTION =\s*\(ADDRESS *= *\(PROTOCOL *= *TCP\)\(HOST *= *(?<host>\w+)\)\(PORT *= *(?<port>\d+)\)\)\s*\(CONNECT_DATA *=\s*(?<serverdedicated>\(SERVER *= *DEDICATED\))\s*\(SERVICE_NAME *= *(?<servicename>[\w\.]+) *\)\s*\)\s*\)`

This pattern matches MYSCHEMA only, but I had to add every element that appeared in MYSCHEMA entry, and it won't match MYOTHERSCHEMA if it does not contain all the same elements.

Ideally, I'd like a pattern that matches MYSCHEMA entry only, and captures HOST, PORT and SERVICE NAME, and optionally (SERVER = DEDICATED) (which I didn't have in the first pattern) to named groups.

Below is the sample tnsnames that I've been using for testing:

```
SOMESCHEMA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = REMOTEHOST)(PORT = 1234))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = REMOTE)
    )
  )

MYSCHEMA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = 1234))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE.LOCAL )
    )
  )

MYOTHERSCHEMA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = 1234))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE.REMOTE)
    )

  )

SOMEOTHERSCHEMA = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1234))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = LOCAL)
    )
  )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing tnsnames.ora in Visual C# 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243022/parsing-tnsnames-ora-in-visual-c-2008)

Comment: Regex doesn't work great with balanced parentheses, see the link in the previous comment for a better solution.

Comment: @Kobi - I can't justify adding another third party product to our development environment for something that can be accomplished through other means.

Comment: Welton - That is your business, but I'd use the parser. The posted solution doesn't have much code, but is has a regex few people can understand and support, and I don't know if it supports the [full syntax](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ibE56lBbYc0J:www.antlr.org/grammar/1088808726810/jdbc-url.g+tnsnames.ora+grammar&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk) - it might fail one night... Of course, it's possible this is exactly what you need. Just giving an alternative. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I haven't found a compelling answer to this issue (no offense @Mikael Svenson), I have just stuck with the second pattern listed in my question.  It is sufficient for the time being, as the tnsnames.ora file always follows that exact pattern within our organization.  Should the tnsnames.ora file format change, I will most likely adopt a parser.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, using balanced groups. And modify the switch/case for your needs.

```
class TnsRegex
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Regex reTns = new Regex(_pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        MatchCollection matchCollection = reTns.Matches(_text);

        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["Settings"].Captures)
            {
                string[] setting = capture.Value.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string key = setting[0].Trim();
                string val = setting[1].Trim();
                if (val.Contains("(")) continue;
                switch (key)
                {
                    case "HOST":
                        break;
                    case "PORT":
                        break;
                    case "SERVICE_NAME":
                        break;
                    case "SERVER":
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(key + ":" + val);
            }
        }
    }
    string _pattern = @"
        MYSCHEMA\s+=\s+\(
        [^\(\)]*
        (
                    (
                                (?<Open>\()
                                [^\(\)]*
                    )+
                    (
                                (?<Settings-Open>\))
                                [^\(\)]*
                    )+
        )*
        (?(Open)(?!))
    \)";

    string _text = @"
    MYSCHEMA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = 1234))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE.LOCAL )
        )
      )

    SOMESCHEMA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = REMOTEHOST)(PORT = 1234))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = REMOTE)
        )
      )
    ";
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution above, replacing the long strings of literal spaces with \s*, but it stops finding any matches when I include the Settings-Open group.

Comment: Keep the literal spaces.. they are taken care of with the RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace option. If you want to remove them, just delete the whitespace, don't replace it.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I had just copied the regular expression pattern into RegexBuddy to do a quick test on my sample, and ran into the problem mentioned above.  I hadn't noticed the RegexOptions.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will parse out individual TNS entries, and all you have to do is parse each result how you see fit for the names / values

`([\w-]+)\s*=(?:\s|.)+?\)\s*\)\s*\)\s*(?=[\w\-])`

Example: https://regexr.com/3r2vn

Answer (score 0):

This expression parse the schema with one address on address_list,  etc.
Hope this helps.

*--begin
(?>((?[\n][\s]*[^(][\w_.]+)[\s]*=[\s]*))(?>(?[\n\s(]*DESCRIPTION[\s=\s]*(?>(?[\n\s(]*ADDRESS_LIST[\s=\s]*[\n\s(]*ADDRESS[\s=\s]*(?([\n\s(]COMMUNITY)([\n\s(]COMMUNITY[\s=\s]*(?[\w.)]+))|())[\s\n]*(?([\n\s(]PROTOCOL)([\n\s(]PROTOCOL[\s=\s]*(?[\w.)]+))|())[\s\n]*(?([\n\s(]HOST)([\n\s(]HOST[\s=\s]*(?[\w.)]+))|())[\s\n]*(?([\n\s(]PORT)([\n\s(]PORT[\s=\s]*(?[\w.)]+))|())[\s\n]*(?())())|())))[\s\n]*(?>(?[\n][\s]*[(]CONNECT_DATA\s*[=]\s*[\n]*(?([(]SID\s*[=]\s*)(([(]SID\s*[=]\s*(?[\w.]+)\s*[)]))|())[\s\n]*(?([(]SERVER\s*[=]\s*)(([(]SERVER\s*[=]\s*(?[\w.]+)\s*[)]))|())[\s\n]*(?([(]SERVICE_NAME\s*[=]\s*)(([(]SERVICE_NAME\s*[=]\s*(?[\w.]+)\s*[)]))|())[\s\n]*(?())())|())))[\s\n]*(?())())|())))
*--end

Undoubtedly, the problem is the multiple that is in the form of writing that file. As you say the file must be unique, this is solved by using the TNS_ADMIN variable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above answers and none of them worked for me ...

```
    [DebuggerDisplay("Name {Name} Host:{Host} ServiceName:{ServiceName} Port:{Port}")]
    public class TnsEntry
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    }


   public class TnsNamesFileParser
   {
    public string TNSNamesContents { get; set; }

    public TnsNamesFileParser()
    {
    }

    public TnsNamesFileParser(string locationAndNameOfTnsNamesFile)
    {
        TNSNamesContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(locationAndNameOfTnsNamesFile);
    }

    public List<TnsEntry> Parse()
    {
        return Parse(TNSNamesContents);
    }

    public List<TnsEntry> Parse(string TNSNamesContents)
    {
        string TNSPattern = @"([\w -] +)\s *= (?:\s |.) +?\)\s *\)\s *\)\s * ((?=[\w\-])|(?=$))";

        Regex reTns = new Regex(TNSPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        MatchCollection matchCollection = reTns.Matches(TNSNamesContents);

        var TnsEntries = new List<TnsEntry>();

        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            var tnsEntry = new TnsEntry();
            string matchedValue = match.Value.Trim();

            tnsEntry.Name = Regex.Match(matchedValue, @"^([^\s]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)?.Value.Trim();
            tnsEntry.Host = Regex.Match(matchedValue, "(?<=HOST.+=) ([^)]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)?.Value.Trim();
            tnsEntry.Port = Regex.Match(matchedValue, "(?<=PORT.+=) ([^)]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)?.Value.Trim();
            tnsEntry.ServiceName = Regex.Match(matchedValue, "(?<=SERVICE_NAME.+=) ([^)]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)?.Value;

            TnsEntries.Add(tnsEntry);

        }

        return TnsEntries;
    }
  }

//Test Code: 

string testdata =@"
        SOMESCHEMA =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = REMOTEHOST)(PORT = 1234))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = REMOTE)
        )
        )

        MYSCHEMA =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = 1234))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE.LOCAL )
        )
        )

        MYOTHERSCHEMA =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = 1234))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA = 
        (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE.REMOTE)
        )
        )

        SOMEOTHERSCHEMA = 
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1234))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = LOCAL)
        )
        )";
 [Test]
 public void ParseTNSFileEntries()
 {

  var tnsNamesFileParser = new TnsNamesFileParser();
  var entries =  tnsNamesFileParser.Parse(testdata);


 }
```