# Parsing tnsnames.ora with regex to just get name

Tags: regex

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549863/parsing-tnsnames-ora-using-regex) and am trying to do kind of the opposite.  This poster wants to capture the information about the connection, where I want to just match on all the connection names. Consider this file:

```
SOMESCHEMA =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = REMOTEHOST)(PORT = 1234))
     )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
 (SERVICE_NAME = REMOTE)
     )   
)  
# comment
MYSCHEMA.world =
   (DESCRIPTION =     
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYHOST)(PORT = 1234))     
(CONNECT_DATA =       
(SERVER = DEDICATED)       
(SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE.LOCAL )     
)   )

##comment
##comment
MY.OTHER.SCHEMA=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MYHOST)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYSERVICE.REMOTE)))  


SOMEOTHERSCHEMA =    (DESCRIPTION =     (ADDRESS_LIST =       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1234))     )     (CONNECT_DATA =       (SERVICE_NAME = LOCAL)   )   )
```

The RexEx rules should be simple enough, I'm just horrible with RegExs.  It should be:

- Match any word (not breaking on ".") that is followed by an "=", disregarding spaces, that is not DESCRIPTION, ADDRESS_LIST, ADDRESS, PROTOCOL, HOST, PORT, CONNECT_DATA or SERVICE NAME.
- Ignore words preceded by a #, again disregarding spaces.

Any RegEx experts that can help with this?  The "disregarding spaces" requirement could be eliminated by removing the whitespace in code first, if that helps.

The result should match:

- SOMESCHEMA
- MYSCHEMA.world
- MY.OTHER.SCHEMA
- SOMEOTHERSCHEMA

Comment: Can we ignore anything preceded by a '(' ? That would make it quite easy.

Comment: Yes. That would be a valid rule.

Comment: Will they always have the word schema in them?

Comment: This will work for the current data set but it depends on whether theres always Schema in it : http://rubular.com/r/NMtYDv5evC

Comment: No they may not always have the word schema.  It could be anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to do it.

http://rubular.com/r/o9AjrFUq5q

```
^([^#()\W ][a-zA-Z.]*(?:[.][a-zA-Z]*\s?=)?)
```

Makes sure the first character is not a #() or word boundary.

Grabs everything up to the final period, and then an optional space before the = sign. A bit convoluted, but it seems to work.

Comment: I'm only getting the first match on other regex testers (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). Is this a function of the regex or the language (ruby vs. c#)?

Comment: I'm at school right now on a tablet,so I can't provide a more complete answer, but I assume it's a difference in regex style between the languages.

Comment: I was able to use a varation of your answer combined with some C# code to get what I'm after.  Thanks for your help.  Get back to class!

Comment: What did you change, I'm interested to know the difference in C#

Comment: I prepped the content by removing whitespace and lines starting with "#" in my code.  Then I used `\b(?<!\()(?<!#)([^\W][_0-9a-zA-Z.]*(?==))`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I want to add a useful reference when Regex isn't the way to go. You can use ANTLR to parse the entire tnsnames.ora (as well as sqlnet.ora, etc.).

You can find a reference to [this grammar](http://www.harward.us/~nharward/antlr/OracleNetServicesV3.g) at the [grammar list](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html) at antlr3.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oracle.net.jdbc.nl.NLParamParser` from the oracle driver jar to help

```java
import oracle.net.jdbc.nl.NLParamParser;

...

try (Reader reader = new FileReader("c:/path/to/tnsnames.ora")) {
    NLParamParser parser = new NLParamParser(reader);

    System.out.println("NLPAllNames: " + Arrays.toString(parser.getNLPAllNames()));
    System.out.println("NLPListSize: " + parser.getNLPListSize());
    System.out.println("NLPAllElements: " + Arrays.toString(parser.getNLPAllElements()));

    for (String name : parser.getNLPAllNames()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("NLPListElement(%s): %s", name, parser.getNLPListElement(name)));
    }
}
```