# How do I programmatically list all projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, scripting, projects-and-solutions

How do I programmatically list all of the projects in a solution? I'll take a script, command-line, or API calls.

Answer (score 75):

Here's a PowerShell script that retrieves project details from a .sln file:

```
Get-Content 'Foo.sln' |
  Select-String 'Project\(' |
    ForEach-Object {
      $projectParts = $_ -Split '[,=]' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim('[ "{}]') };
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $projectParts[1];
        File = $projectParts[2];
        Guid = $projectParts[3]
      }
    }
```

Comment: I know this is old, but it is beautiful. Saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: If you need to, you can filter out solution folders by adding an additional Select-String between lines 2 and 3 as follows: `Select-String "{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}" -NotMatch |`

Answer (score 21):

```
    var Content = File.ReadAllText(SlnPath);
    Regex projReg = new Regex(
        "Project\\(\"\\{[\\w-]*\\}\"\\) = \"([\\w _]*.*)\", \"(.*\\.(cs|vcx|vb)proj)\""
        , RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var matches = projReg.Matches(Content).Cast<Match>();
    var Projects = matches.Select(x => x.Groups[2].Value).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < Projects.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(Projects[i]))
            Projects[i] = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(SlnPath),
                Projects[i]);
        Projects[i] = Path.GetFullPath(Projects[i]);
    }
```

Edit: Amended the regex to include the ".*" as per the comment by Kumar Vaibhav

Comment: The above works but there is a little problem. If your projects are named like "AB.CD" - I mean when the '.' is there then the regex would not recognize those. The following little change would make it work - Regex projReg = new Regex(
                "Project\\(\"\\{[\\w-]*\\}\"\\) = \"([\\w _]*.*)\", \"(.*\\.(cs|vcx|vb)proj)\""
                , RegexOptions.Compiled);

Comment: Can anyone explain why you need `IsPathRooted` here? Not sure why a project would ever be rooted, because I've never seen such a solution file.

Answer (score 13):

The trick is to choose the right MsBuild.dll.
Under VS2017 it is indeed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.dll"
(Dont use the standard Msbuild ddl in references. Browse to this path)

c#:

```
var solutionFile =    
SolutionFile.Parse(@"c:\NuGetApp1\NuGetApp1.sln");//your solution full path name
var projectsInSolution = solutionFile.ProjectsInOrder;
foreach(var project in projectsInSolution)
{
   switch (project.ProjectType)
   {
      case SolutionProjectType.KnownToBeMSBuildFormat:
     {
         break;
     }
     case SolutionProjectType.SolutionFolder:
     {
         break;
     }
  }
}
```

powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + '\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.dll')

$slnPath = 'c:\NuGetApp1\NuGetApp1.sln'
$slnFile = [Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile]::Parse($slnPath)
$pjcts = $slnFile.ProjectsInOrder

foreach ($item in $pjcts)
{

    switch($item.ProjectType)
    {
        'KnownToBeMSBuildFormat'{Write-Host Project  : $item.ProjectName}
        'SolutionFolder'{Write-Host Solution Folder : $item.ProjectName}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the EnvDTE.Solution.Projects object to programmatically get access to the projects in a solution.

One gotcha though is that if you have any SolutionFolders in your solution, any projects in these folders are not shown in the above collection.

I've written an article including a code sample on how [to get all projects](https://wwwlicious.com/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/) regardless of any solutionfolders

Comment: This can only be used in a VS extension, so it useless for anybody who wants a stand alone tool for reading source projects in a solution.

Comment: You can get a reference to a [running instance of VS](https://github.com/wwwlicious/VSAutomate/blob/master/VSAutomate/Ide.cs#L25) or you can access `$dte` from the package manager console.

If you dont have VS running at all then you need an alternative solution. The new MSBuild packages now contain classes for parsing solution and project files but these are still pre-RTM

Comment: updated link:  https://wwwlicious.com/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/

Answer (score 9):

Currently you can use [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console) in VS to obtain that info. Use powershell `Get-Project` command

```
Get-Project -All
```

Comment: Which **Visual Studio** _**`version`**_ ?

Comment: This gets the full project name for really long project names and sorts the output too: Get-Project -All | Select-Object ProjectName,FullName | Sort-Object -Property ProjectName

Answer (score 7):

from powershelll and in the solution's folder write

dotnet sln list

Answer (score 5):

just read the list from *.sln file. There are "Project"-"EndProject" sections.

Here is [an article from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb165951%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @Kiquenet I'm afraid I didn't understand your comment

Comment: not any **Parser C# class** for read _sln files_ ? Similar like ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/parsing-visual-studio-solution-files*** **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243022/parsing-tnsnames-ora-in-visual-c-sharp-2008**

Answer (score 3):

If you write your program as Visual Studio Add-in you can access the [`EnvDTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx) to find out all the projects within the currently opened solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's a really elegant solution here: [Parsing Visual Studio Solution files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files)

The answer by John Leidegren involves wrapping the internal `Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionParser` class.

Answer (score 3):

Since Visual Studio 2013 the Microsoft.Build.dll provides a SolutionFile object with some very handy functions.

Here's an example of using the v14.0 version to list the relative path of all the projects in the order they appear in the solution.

```
Add-Type -Path (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + '\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\MSBuild\v14.0\Microsoft.Build.dll')
$solutionFile = '<FULL PATH TO SOLUTION FILE>'
$solution = [Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile] $solutionFile
($solution.ProjectsInOrder | Where-Object {$_.ProjectType -eq 'KnownToBeMSBuildFormat'}).RelativePath
```

There are plenty of other properties on the project object (ProjectName, AbsolutePath, configurations etc) that may be of use. In the above example I used the ProjectType to filter out Solution Folders.

Comment: For VS2017, it is under VS2017 ```"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.dll" ```
And annoying, but for sqlprojs files, project type is Unknown ```[SolutionProjectType]::Unknown```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is maybe already answered question, but I would like to share my approach of reading sln file. Also during run time I am determining if project is Test project or not

```
function ReadSolutionFile($solutionName)
{
    $startTime = (Get-Date).Millisecond
    Write-Host "---------------Read Start---------------" 
    $solutionProjects = @()

    dotnet  sln "$solutionName.sln" list | ForEach-Object{     
        if($_  -Match ".csproj" )
        {
            #$projData = ($projectString -split '\\')

            $proj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{

                Project = [string]$_;
                IsTestProject =   If ([string]$_ -Match "test") {$True} Else {$False}  
            }

            $solutionProjects += $proj

        }
    }

    Write-Host "---------------Read finish---------------" 
    $solutionProjects

    $finishTime = (Get-Date).Millisecond
    Write-Host "Script run time: $($finishTime-$startTime) mil" 
}
```

Hope this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this on a non Windows machine, you can use the following Bash command:

`grep "Project(" NameOfYourSolution.sln | cut -d'"' -f4`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802263/422335) by [@brianpeiris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22417/brianpeiris):

```
Function Global:Get-ProjectInSolution {
    [CmdletBinding()] param (
        [Parameter()][string]$Solution
    )
    $SolutionPath = Join-Path (Get-Location) $Solution
    $SolutionFile = Get-Item $SolutionPath
    $SolutionFolder = $SolutionFile.Directory.FullName

    Get-Content $Solution |
        Select-String 'Project\(' |
        ForEach-Object {
            $projectParts = $_ -Split '[,=]' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim('[ "{}]') }
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                File = $projectParts[2]
                Guid = $projectParts[3]
                Name = $projectParts[1]
            }
        } |
        Where-Object File -match "csproj$" |
        ForEach-Object {
            Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName FullName -NotePropertyValue (Join-Path $SolutionFolder $_.File) -PassThru
        }
}
```

This filters to only `.csproj` files and adds the full path of each based on the `File` field and the path containing the `sln` file.

Use `Get-ProjectInSolution MySolution.sln | Select-Object FullName` to get each of the full file paths.

The reason I wanted the full path was to be able to access the `packages.config` files beside each project file and then get the packages from all of them:

```
Get-ProjectInSolution MySolution.sln |
    %{Join-Path ($_.FullName | Split-Path) packages.config} |
    %{select-xml "//package[@id]" $_ | %{$_.Node.GetAttribute("id")}} |
    select -unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified approach I used to look at the problem from a Solution-first stance:

```
Function Get-ProjectReferences ($rootFolder) {
    $ns = @{ defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }
    $solutionFilesWithContent = Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Filter *.sln -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            SolutionFile    = $_;
            SolutionContent = Get-Content $_;
        }
    }
    $projectFilesWithContent = Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Filter *.csproj -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            ProjectFile    = $_;
            ProjectContent = [xml](Get-Content $_);
        }  
    }

    $solutionFilesWithContent | ForEach-Object {
        $solutionFileWithContent = $_
        $projectsInSolutionStrings = $solutionFileWithContent.SolutionContent | Select-String 'Project\('
        $projectsInSolution = $projectsInSolutionStrings |
        ForEach-Object {
            $projectParts = $_ -Split '[,=]' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim('[ "{}]') };
            if ($projectParts[2].Contains(".csproj")) {
                New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Name = $projectParts[1];
                    File = $projectParts[2];
                    Guid = $projectParts[3];
                }                    
            }
        }

        $projectsInSolution | ForEach-Object {
            $projectFileSearchName = $_.Name + ".csproj"
            $projectInSolutionFile = $projectFilesWithContent | Where-Object { $_.ProjectFile.Name -eq $projectFileSearchName } | Select-Object -First 1
            if (($null -eq $projectInSolutionFile) -and ($null -eq $projectInSolutionFile.ProjectContent)) {
                Write-Host "Project was null"
            }
            else {
                $projectInSolutionName = $projectInSolutionFile.ProjectFile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
                $projectReferences = $projectInSolutionFile.ProjectContent | Select-Xml '//defaultNamespace:ProjectReference/defaultNamespace:Name' -Namespace $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
                $projectTarget = $projectInSolutionFile.ProjectContent | Select-Xml "//defaultNamespace:TargetFrameworkVersion" -Namespace $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
        
                $projectReferences | ForEach-Object {
                    $projectFileName = $_ + ".csproj"
                    $referenceProjectFile = $projectFilesWithContent | Where-Object { $_.ProjectFile.Name -eq $projectFileName } | Select-Object -First 1
                    if ($null -eq $referenceProjectFile) {
                        $referenceProjectTarget = "Unknown"
                    }
                    else {
                        $referenceProjectTarget = $referenceProjectFile.ProjectContent | Select-Xml "//defaultNamespace:TargetFrameworkVersion" -Namespace $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"                    
                    }
                    "[" + $solutionFileWithContent.SolutionFile.Name + "] -> [" + $projectInSolutionName + " " + $projectTarget + "] -> [" + $_ + " " + $referenceProjectTarget + "]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-ProjectReferences "C:\src\repos\MyRepo" | Out-File "C:\src\repos\FrameworkDependencyAnalysis\FrameworkDependencyAnalysis.txt"
```

Comment: For Net Framework or Net Core (Net 5, 6,...) ?

Comment: In this case I was focused on .NET Framework, because my department has a large inventory of .NET Framework projects still targeting 4.5.* and we're starting an effort to move them to 4.8.