# TFS 2015 Visual Studio Build project variables

Tags: tfs-2015

I have a Visual Studio Build definition that compiles solution1.sln. It has 2 web projects: WebProject1, and WebApiProject2.

Is there any what to get those names (WebProject1, WebApiProject2) automatically into variables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Powershell step to retrieve project names from a .sln file and then set the project names into variables.

[Get project names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802027/how-do-i-programmatically-list-all-projects-in-a-solution):

```
Get-Content 'xxx.sln' |
  Select-String 'Project\(' |
    ForEach-Object {
      $projectParts = $_ -Split '[,=]' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim('[ "{}]') };
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $projectParts[1];

      }
    }
```

Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. Check [##vso[task.setvariable]value](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) for more information.

Example:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;issecret=true;]testvalue
```

Comment: can you explain how to set the variables? Is that part written in the same powershell as when getting the project names?

Comment: You can get projects name and set them into variable in one powershell. The variable will be exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.