# ComboBox to look up Solutions and Projects

Tags: c#, tfs, combobox

we currently use a windows UI form and ComboBox to select a particular test to run. Within the code we specifically feed in the name of the tests to run that get passed to the application to run them.
I'm just wondering if there is a way to get the ComboBox in the UI form to read through the explorer under the default collection, or a folder within that and pull the names of the solutions and the projects within the solution.

For eg
ComboBox_1 would find the solutions in a folder and you could select one.
ComboBox_2 would look inside the chosen solution for all the projects under it and one of these could be selected.
Button_1 would then run the selected project.

Please let me know if you need anything else or if that isn't clear.
Cheers in advance.

Comment: Does this need to be from TFS, rather than the local file system?   If so I think you'll have to use the TFS REST API or, more simply, a TFS command-line tool to update a local copy of the TFS content that you can then navigate

Answer (score 0):

You can list files under a folder and filter them by files that has ".sln" extension. this will be the solution files in the folder.

```
string[] files=Directory.GetFiles("folder path");
        List<string> lstSolutions = new List<string>();
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (file.Contains(".sln"))
                lstSolutions.Add(file);
        }
```

Then you can use something like this to get projects in the solution

```
var Content = File.ReadAllText(SlnPath);
Regex projReg = new Regex(
    "Project\\(\"\\{[\\w-]*\\}\"\\) = \"([\\w _]*.*)\", \"(.*\\.(cs|vcx|vb)proj)\""
    , RegexOptions.Compiled);
var matches = projReg.Matches(Content).Cast<Match>();
var Projects = matches.Select(x => x.Groups[2].Value).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < Projects.Count; ++i)
{
    if (!Path.IsPathRooted(Projects[i]))
        Projects[i] = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(SlnPath),
            Projects[i]);
    Projects[i] = Path.GetFullPath(Projects[i]);
}
```

[List projects in a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14772471/5769970)

Comment: Ok, getting somewhere now. I have used your 1st snippet and have a combobox populated with the .sln files. How do I then run the 2nd snippet you provided in a separate combo to pull the projects?

Comment: You can define the second code snippet as a function and pass the solution path as a parameter. It takes solution path and populates the Projects list with projects , including the full path