# How to use Package Manager Console powershell outside visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, nuget-package, package-manager-console

I have a powershell script which has nuget commands like:

> Get-Project -All
>
> Get-Package -ProjectName

When I run package manager console on visual studio like:

> PM> .\download-packages-license.ps1

It worked but I cannot run powershell. I need a hlp.

Powershell error message:

> download-packages-license.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/
>   fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + .\download-packages-license.ps1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to use Package Manager Console powershell outside visual studio

I am afraid you could not use Package Manager Console powershell outside visual studio. That because package manager console is providing is access to **visual studio objects**:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1512

So, if you want use Package Manager Console powershell outside visual studio, we have to parse the `.csproj` file or `.sln` solution file with powershell manually, like:

[How do I programmatically list all projects in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802027/how-do-i-programmatically-list-all-projects-in-a-solution)

Hope this helps.