# How to programmatically determine what kind is a .NET project

Tags: .net

How to programmatically determine if my project is .NET Foundation or .NET Standard?
Or, alternatively, how to programmatically determine if Xamarin.IOS or Windows Forms.

This is for a .Net Standard class lib that will run on either .NET Xamarin.IOS on an iPhone or a .NET Windows forms app on a Windows 10 laptop.

The app needs to know which of these platforms it is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio uses GUIDs to identify a Project Type. As mentioned in [tekeye blog post](https://tekeye.uk/visual_studio/microsoft-visual-studio-project-type-guids-and-project-guids):

> This allows for developers in different companies to call projects by
>   the same name, but if they come across each other's work the same
>   named projects would still be uniquely identifiable by Visual Studio.

GUIDs generated for project types are placed in `.csproj` file under `ProjectTypeGuids` and `.sln` file under `Project`.

In `.csproj` file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{FEACFBD2-3405-455C-9665-78FE426C6842};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

In `.sln` file:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WindowsFormsTestApp", "WindowsFormsTestAppWindowsFormsTestApp.csproj", "{F00515D6-939F-4E92-8FFD-A5D8F811FF84}"
```

You can find a complete list of GUIDs in Tekeye blog post linked above.

To grab this programmatically from `.csproj` file you can use snippet below:

```
XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
XDocument projDefinition = XDocument.Load("projectPath\file.csproj");
IEnumerable<string> references = projDefinition
    .Element(msbuild + "Project")
    .Elements(msbuild + "PropertyGroup")
    .Elements(msbuild + "ProjectTypeGuids")  
    .Select(refElem => refElem.Value);
```

If you didn't find `ProjectTypeGuids` in `.csproj` file, you can find Guid in `.sln` file by parsing the file using regex as @watbywbarif did in [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14772471/6311045).

Comment: That seems complex and I'm concerned will take hours of development time.  I'm looking to call some .Net function that returns a code that indicates the app is Windows Forms or Xamarin.IOS or .Net Foundation or .Net Standard.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the only way to achieve your goal. But there's another way that I don't think it's the solution that suites your problem or even you'll like it. You can use visual studio automation to make a add-in to get access to project properties window in c#, and then call that add-in in your code. But i don't think that's a good idea.