# Enumerating Oracle Database names for a specified server

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

How can I enumerate Oracle Database names in C#?

I am able to query all available databases for a MSSQL connection string:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Password=TestPassword;User ID=TestUser;Data Source=localhost"))
{
    con.Open();

    return con.GetSchema("Databases")
                .Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                .Select(row => row.Field<string>("database_name"))
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: `Every oracle db instance has only One database`, in this case it's completely different from MS SQL Server

Comment: Some useful reading https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1631683800346891854

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ODP.NET, you can use the `OracleDataSourceEnumerator` to list the TNS entries. See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataSourceEnumeratorClass.htm).

If not then you'll have to [parse the tnsnames.ora yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243022/parsing-tnsnames-ora-in-visual-c-sharp-2008).