# Parsing file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, tnsnames

I have tnsnames.ora file which includes 50+ aliases. Added example content below.

Currently I use below code to get aliases from tns;

```
tnsnamesreadercustom tsc = new tnsnamesreadercustom();
uceTNS.DataSource = tsc.LoadTNSNames(FilePath);
```

And I parse these tnsnames aliases into combobox successfully like ;

```
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
```

But i couldn't finish the last step which is;

**User selects the above aliases for example NAME1 and it should get the details on messagebox like;**

```
HOST:name1.local.com
PORT:1521
SERVICE_NAME:nameone
SID=null
```

Here is the tnsnames.ora example;

```
NAME1=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=name1.local.com)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=nameone)
    )
  )

NAME2= 
  (DESCRIPTION= 
    (ADDRESS= 
      (PROTOCOL=TCP) 
      (HOST=172.31.60.227) 
      (PORT=1531) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA= 
      (SERVER=dedicated) 
      (SID=nametwo) 
    ) 
  ) 

NAME3= 
  (DESCRIPTION= 
    (ADDRESS= 
      (PROTOCOL=TCP) 
      (HOST=172.31.70.174) 
      (PORT=1521) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA= 
      (SERVER=dedicated) 
      (SERVICE_NAME=namethree) 
    ) 
  )
```

Here is the tnsnamesreadercustom;

```
   class tnsnamesreadercustom
    {
        public List<string> LoadTNSNames(string strTNSNAMESORAFilePath)
        {
            List<string> DBNamesCollection = new List<string>();
            string RegExPattern = @"[\n][\s]*[^\(][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[\s]*=[\s]*\(";

            if (!strTNSNAMESORAFilePath.Equals(""))
            {
                //check out that file does physically exists
                System.IO.FileInfo fiTNS = new System.IO.FileInfo(strTNSNAMESORAFilePath);
                if (fiTNS.Exists)
                {
                    if (fiTNS.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //read tnsnames.ora file
                        int iCount;
                        for (iCount = 0; iCount < Regex.Matches(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fiTNS.FullName), RegExPattern).Count; iCount++)
                        {
                            DBNamesCollection.Add(Regex.Matches(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fiTNS.FullName), RegExPattern)[iCount].Value.Trim().Substring(0, Regex.Matches(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fiTNS.FullName), RegExPattern)[iCount].Value.Replace("=", " ").Trim().IndexOf(" ")).Replace(" ", "").Replace("=", "").Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return DBNamesCollection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `tnsnamesreadercustom`? Might help if you posted some code.

Comment: @ well, it just regexp the aliases, i just shared

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243022/parsing-tnsnames-ora-in-visual-c-sharp-2008)?

Comment: @Dean They are parsing aliases not parameters.

Comment: I also found this which might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/224853/Enumerate-entries-in-TNSNames-ora-using-Oracle-pro.

Comment: @Polyfun Thank you but i am not using Oracle.DataAccess.Client. I tried this about 2 days ago. but no luck.

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/espenrl/TnsNames) looks useful as well, and is available as a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/erl.Oracle.TnsNames/). I'm not sure I understand your point about aliases versus parameters. The linked-to ANTLR grammar looks like it for sure supports parameters.

Comment: this looks like a TNSNAMES.ora file. Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549863/

Comment: Side note unrelated to question: Why do you repeatedly read the file (_strTNSNAMESORAFilePath_) again, again, and again (_System.IO.File.ReadAllText_)? Why did you not read it just once into a string variable and then use the string variable? And why do you repeatedly do the same regex pattern match on the same string (file content) again and again, instead of doing it just once and then using the resulting MatchCollection? Not only is it poor performance-wise (doesn't probably matter), but it also is unnecessary code duplication with code readability going out of the window...